# Parse rendered HTML using Java

Tags: java, html, renderer, html-rendering

I want to print complete rendered HTML using Java.For this I searched a lot on Google and also found some questions on SO Like

1: [How do you render HTML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242757/how-do-you-render-html-using-java)

2: [HTML parsing using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623427/html-parsing-using-java) 
3: [Rendering (streaming) HTML into Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127112/rendering-streaming-html-into-pane)

But unfortunately they were not helpful for me.
So the thing which I want to print is a rendered HTML. When I try do it with using simple java , Then it didn't print the executed JavaScript (instead it prints the JavaScript which is written in the HTML page). 
 Please Guide me about this
 **SO SIMPLY I AM TRYING TO PRINT THE RENDERED HTML BY BROWSER (not the html file present at web server) INCLUDING EXECUTED JAVASCRIPT.** 
Thanks

Comment: JSoup? It's what I use to parse HTML. Not sure if it renders but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of packages that you can find that are similar to [Hypirinha](http://code.google.com/p/hypirinha/)  on the net , if you look for them.

There is probably a better answer than mine, but I thought this would be an idea that might work for you.

Also, here is a [JavaFX example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/webview/printing.htm), but I am not sure if it suits your purpose.

Comment: Let me ask simply: Does this API have methods who print ALL RENDERED html on console as a String?

Comment: Yes, there is an example on that page, but of course, you need to create the JavaFX (or Swing) console yourself, which is a pretty simple thing to find on the net.

Comment: I dont want to capture all elements one by one becuase I dont know what is in HTML which I am trying to parse.So will this API works for this? because I seen that It have methods which capture them through body , head etc

Comment: Sorry, I am not completely understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I AM TRYING TO PRINT THE RENDERED HTML BY BROWSER (not the html file present at web server) INCLUDING EXECUTED JAVASCRIPT.The code return the html written in file NOT THE HTML RENDERED IN BROWSER.Simply I wan to get that HTML which we can see using firebug

Comment: That's easy.  You can use PhantomJS or Selenium and just call the getSource() method.  As the dom changes, with user interaction, the getSource() method will get the latest version of the DOM content.

Comment: I really appreciate your help .Selenium webDriver/firefoxDriver's getSource() returns the page source without executed javascript.I have tried it and didn't get the portion of javascript as executed :( .. May be I need a thing work like Web Server :( Please Guide me more about this if you can

Comment: You might be able to use the Selenium JavascriptExecutore class to get it.  Basically, you can use JavaScript to get the JavaScript headers.  You can test your ideas using the Firebug Javascript console.  Just a thought.  I am running out of ideas for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a `SimpleBrowser` component to get html from a `WebView`. Usage:

```
SimpleBrowser browser = new SimpleBrowser();

Scene scene = new Scene(browser);

browser.load("http://stackoverflow.com", new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(browser.getHTML());
    }
});
```

Code is available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20135387/1851024) or in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chaschev/7593327).

Comment: Seems good :) I have no knowledge about javafx.Does this code works in simple java project?

Comment: Yes, this requires JDK 7. It also runs in JDK 8 early access.

Comment: Actually I want to do it in Java not in JavaFX

Comment: JavaFX is a part of JDK since early versions of JDK7, it's just the same good old Java which adopted the WebKit engine. :-)

Comment: I have tried your solution But I didn't work.I guess you are not getting my point.I AM TRYING TO PRINT THE RENDERED HTML BY BROWSER (not the html file present at web server) INCLUDING EXECUTED JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: I guess you're doing something wrong. JavaFX renders html with JavaScript: [Google Maps in Javafx 2.0](http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/).